# Pass 2 dimentinal array(or array of objects) via Request.Form?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm using ASP.NET Web forms, and I need to pass 2D array, or array of objects using javascript ajax to the server.

Comment: are you using a Get or Post Call??

Comment: I'm using Post call.

Comment: are you getting some error? you can send a 2d array in the same way that you work with a simple array

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors when solving my problem in proposed way. I just thought that maybe there is any way to loop within Request object. so it would look like: Request.Form["SomeArray"][i], or smth like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass it as a one dimensional array and since you know the array dimension you can know what is the value for each cell.

For example, 2x2 array:

In C#:

```
int[] arr =       {22, 44 ,55 ,66};
```

// Cell Location  00  01  10  11

In JS:

```
var arr = ["22", "44", "55",  "66"];
```

Even if you do not know the array size, you can pass it as rows & columns parameters when calling your server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry pal int[] does not exist in javascript

Comment: @melaspelas:  I was providing the example in C# since this is the server side component. for JS it would be: var arr = ["22", "44", "55"]; i provided the concept on how to pass 2D array and this is the essence of the answer.

Comment: I got it, but may be your workaround does not fit for array of objects escenario. I admit it, sometimes to send data from javascript to MVC .net or aspx could be tricky but it exists a lot of good practices to handle it that.